# why 'undefined ' comes in output , when i nest 2 console . logs using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

why undefined comes in output , when i nest 2 console . logs?
is there something that i am missing out.
why this unexpected behaiviour?

```
console.log(console.log("hello"))
```

O/P:
hello
undefined

Comment: See [`console.log()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner console.log statement will print 'Hello, world!' to the console, but it will return undefined. The outer console.log statement will then print undefined to the console.

Therefore, if you nest two console.log statements, the inner console.log will print to the console, but the outer console.log will print undefined to the console.